# How to integrate $\int_{\text{n}}^r \left(-s^b-s t+Y\right)^{-c} \, ds$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Any hints on how to integrate the following?

$\int_{\text{n}}^r \left(-s^b-s t+Y\right)^{-c} \, ds$

Comment: Where did you find this monster ? Are you given specific values for $b,c,t,Y$ ?

Comment: c,t and Y are positive constants, but I want to find an optimal b later on in my model

Comment: I am afraid that numerical methods would need to be considered. Could you clarify the context ? It could help.

Comment: unfortunately, I would need an analytic solution

Comment: Good luck, then ! I shall wait for other answers and comments. But, again, could you clarify the context of the problem ?

Comment: would it be solvable if the upper integral bound be s, such that r=s and n some constant?

Comment: what would help as context? it's an integral over a distance-dependent cost across distance s between two points r and n on a line.